# VPS high traffic load

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, performance, vps, godaddy

Hello everyone I am really new on this topic so most of my questions will be trivial.

I buyed a VPS from godaddy which has 4 CPUs 8GB Ram and 200 GB HDD. I set up a one domain and upload my web site it is working good until I was go live.

When more than 300 people try to connect my web site it is loading so slow and usage of resource in VPS is showing %6 of CPU 1.38GB RAM and not getting more than this no matter how many people try to connect.

So my question is how can I use all resources VPS has?

How can I improve performance of my server what should I do ?

I am willing to provide any information about structure and server.

- OS : CentOS
- Web Server: Apache2
- Php: 5.6

Comment: You have to identify a bottleneck. Is it Apache config ( number of threads? Number of simultaneous connections?) Or PHP issue, or disk? It is hard to say without access to your server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could definitely increase the performance of your website by using php 7.0 or later versions.

PHP 7 vs. PHP 5: A Performance Comparison: 
https://www.aerospike.com/blog/php7_php5/